# How to know the source of a process in Linux?

Tags: linux, process

In our firm, we are using Fedora 14. Our developers are using Python code to process documents. All are running as root. Somehow they did something and a file came inside which makes lots and lots of connection to one particular IP, which jammed our whole network. We tried to sort it out. In `/usr/bin`, we found some filthy binaries which are creating these connections. After removing the binary from `/usr/bin`, the same file gets re-created with a different name and again starts to make connection to the IP.

Is there a way to find the program which is creating this executables in `/usr/bin`?

Comment: Are all of them working on single Fedora 14 machine via SSH or something like that ?

Comment: One way might be to enable SELinux and run it in permissive mode, but make it log everything that happens. That way you should be able to see in the according logs what has created the file.

Comment: By the way, once a machine has been owned (foreign programs running as root), there is probably little point in trying to clean it up; essentially anything could have happened (for example, the kernel could have been altered, preventing the usual tools from seeing what is really going on). I recommend reinstalling the entire system from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

That seems like a DDoS trojan. Mostly those trojans are in cronjobs. Stop the cron daemon and check your `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.*` files for multiple cronjobs that create those files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the path of the current executable, look at `/proc/$PID/exe`,

```
ls -l /proc/$PID | grep exe
```